# Any effect of fire in structural design of buildings?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Do we consider possible effects of fire, when we do structural design for reinforced concrete buildings? 
But for steel buildings we do?

Also for reinforced concrete buildings, the thermal expansion difference will not be issue because thermal expansion coefficient of concrete and reinforced steel is very close to each other?

Comment: whoever gave a minus to my question apparently did not see the word "structural" in my question and thought i was asking if generally fire protection is considered. well of course. i was asking from structural point of view only

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Fire protection is a separate part of the design process and code. Structural design assumes that the protection is provided as prescribed by the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Fire protection is important in large building design. For steel I have seen hollow steel columns filled with antifreeze/water, also intumescent coatings are used . Also concrete covering steel ,this concrete may also provide strength. And the sprinkler systems which includes a gravity feed tank at high elevation. Of course local codes take priority but you can exceed them.